# Displaying info of saved Credit Card in an Application Secured?

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card

I've been trying to look for an answer to this question but this isn't clearing me.

Is it safe for an application to display the credit card number and expiry of a saved credit card. 
For eg, I logged into an app and saved a credit card. Now for later purchases, I selected this saved card. So is it fine if it displays the credit card 16 digit number and its expiry? Is it PCI compliant?

Answer (score 1):

The general recommendation is for the server to send back and display the last 4 digits. Reasons :

1. If someone compromised your account, they would still not get your credit card info.
2. If someone was shoulder surfing, they wouldn't get your credit card info.